# How do you access a HTTPS webpage with Python 3.4 by Proxy

Tags: python, https, proxy

I am trying to access a HTTPS webpage that has a login. I can't access it no matter what i do. here is the code i tried below.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http':'http://proxyName:proxyNumber'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://salesforce.com')
datum = response.read()
#.decode("UTF-8")
#response.close()
print(datum)
```

here is the ERROR

```
File S:\...py" line 8 in module
reponse = urllib.request.urlopen("https://salesforce.com)
urllib.error.URLError:(urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Please help

here is another try with new error. I feel like im getting close!

```
import urllib.request
proxies = {'https': 'http://proxyName:ProxyNumber'}
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxies)

#urllib.request.get("https://login.salesforce.com/", proxies=proxies)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://login.salesforce.com/", proxies=proxies)
```

Here is the Error message:

```
File S:/...py, line 6 in (module)
urllib.request.build_opener(proxies)
TypeError:expected BaseHandler instance, got (class 'dict)
```

Comment: Looks like you're connecting to something that doesn't want connections. Are your proxy configuration settings (username/password/port/etc.) correct?

Comment: i didnt add a username/password yet do i need to first? i was just trying to see if i could access the page first. Please forgive for me being stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use third party modules, here is an easy solution with the requests module.

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://proxyName:proxyNumber"
}

requests.get("https://salesforce.com", proxies=proxies, auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

adapted from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: i tried that but in python 3.4 i dont think there is a request import. Correct me if i am wrong. i tried it and still got an error .

Comment: It's a third party module which means it doesn't come installed with Python. In a command prompt run `pip install requests`. You'll then be able to use the requests module.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help.